# How to sort an ObjectList in Digital Micrograph

Tags: dm-script

Is it any possibilities to sort the ObjectList object?
For example:

```
  class MissPlane: object
{
    number  d_local
    object init(object self, number d)
    {
        d_local=d
        return self
    }
            number getD(object self)
    {
        return d_local
    }
    void print(object self)
    {
        result("d="+d_local+"\n")
    }

}
number h,k,l,hmax
hmax=2
result("start----------------"+datestamp()+"----------------------\n")

Object PlaneList
PlaneList=Alloc(ObjectList)
for(l=-hmax;l<=hmax;l++){
    for(k=-hmax;k<=hmax;k++){
        for(h=-hmax;h<=hmax;h++){
            Object MPObject=Alloc(MissPlane)
            MPObject.init(random())
            PlaneList.AddObjectToList(MPObject)
            MPObject.print()
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I need to sort it by d.

PS. ObjectList is not fully documented in the DM manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DM command `sort` to achieve sorting of either **TagLists** or **ObjectList**. In both cases you have to create a "sorting" class which defines a method comparing two elements and returning if the second element is bigger than the first.

The following example is for TagLists, sorting a numeric tagList to have increasing numbers.

```
Class Sorter
{
    // The signature of the following method must not be changed. 
    Number Bigger( Object self, TagGroup TG1, Number index1, TagGroup TG2, Number index2 )
    {
        Number N1, N2
        TG1.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsNumber( index1, N1 )
        TG2.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsNumber( index2, N2 )
        return (N1<N2)?1:0
    }
}

TagGroup CreateRandomList( Number n )
{
    TagGroup list = NewTagList()
    For ( Number i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    list.TagGroupInsertTagAsNumber( i, Random() )
    return list
}

void Main()
{
    TagGroup unsorted = CreateRandomList( 10 ) 
    unsorted.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( "unsorted", 0 )
    Object sortObject = Alloc( Sorter )
    Sort( 0, unsorted, sortObject, "Bigger" )   // The first parameter specifies ‘stable’ search
    unsorted.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( "sorted", 0 )
}
Main()
```

---

The next example is for ObejctLists, sorting an objectList. In this case, objects of the list are simply "wrapped numbers" and the soring again achieves an increasing numbers.

```
class MyObject
{
    Number value
    Object Init( Object self, Number in ) { value = in; return self; }
    Number Get( Object self ) { return value; }
}

Class Sorter
{
    // The signature of the following method must not be changed.
    Number HigherValue( Object self, Object obj1, Object obj2 ) 
    {
        return ( obj1.Get() < obj2.Get() ) ? 1 : 0
    }
}

Object CreateRandomList( Number n )
{
    Object obList = Alloc(ObjectList)
    For ( Number i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ )
    {
        Object newOBJ = Alloc(MyObject).Init( Random() )
        obList.AddObjectToList( newOBJ )
    }
    return obList
}

void PrintObjects( Object obList )
{
    ForEach( Object ob; obList )
        Result( "value:" + ob.Get() + "\n" )
}

void Main()
{
    Object unsorted = CreateRandomList( 7 ) 
    Result( "\nBefore sort:\n" )
    unsorted.PrintObjects()
    Result( "\nAfter sort:\n" )
    Sort( 0, unsorted, Alloc(Sorter), "HigherValue" )
    unsorted.PrintObjects()
}
Main()
```

Both code examples have been found from [this website](http://dmscript.tavernmaker.de).

Answer (score 0):

The following example create a simple "bubble-sort" method to sort your object list:

```
 class MissPlane: object
{
    number  d_local
    object init(object self, number d)
    {
        d_local=d
        return self
    }
            number getD(object self)
    {
        return d_local
    }
    void print(object self)
    {
        result("d="+d_local+"\n")
    }

}

object sortList( object in )
{
    object copy = in.ScriptObjectClone()    // Making a copy avoids messing with your original list...
    object sorted=Alloc(objectlist)

    while( copy.SizeOfList() )
    {
        object t = copy.ObjectAt(0)
        for (number c=1; c<copy.SizeOfList(); c++ )
        {
            if ( t.GetD() > copy.ObjectAt(c).GetD() ) 
                t = copy.ObjectAt(c);   // found a "smaller" object
        }
        sorted.AddObjectToList(t)   // add the smallest item found
        copy.RemoveObjectFromList(t)
    }

    return sorted
}

number h,hmax
hmax=20
result("start----------------"+datestamp()+"----------------------\n")

Object PlaneList
PlaneList=Alloc(ObjectList)
for(h=-0;h<hmax;h++){
    Object MPObject=Alloc(MissPlane)
    MPObject.init(random())
    PlaneList.AddObjectToList(MPObject)
}

result("start---------------- ORIGINAL ----------------------\n")
ForEach( object o; PlaneList )
    o.print()
Object sorted = sortList(PlaneList)
result("start---------------- SORTED ----------------------\n")
ForEach( object o; sorted)
    o.print()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In my DM3 help file one of the methods documented as long ( ScriptObject, long index, ScriptObject element ) 

    //  inserts element before the given index. 

    // Index can be 0 to insert at the beginning of the list. 

    // Index can be 9E9 to add to the end. It returns the index of the new element.
Without name of the method. After 10 min of guessing it is the "InsertObjectintoList".